# How to stream webcam to client in HTML 5

Tags: javascript, php, android, html

The code below only shows `webcam` view of a person who is on the page. but what i want is others to see me live. have look

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>camview</title>        
     </head>        
     <body>
         <video id="vidDisplay" autoplay="true">
            No video support in your browser...
         </video>
         <script>
             navigator.getUserMedia=navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia ||
             navigator.oGetUserMedia;
             if(navigator.getUserMedia){
                 navigator.getUserMedia({video:true}, handleVideo, videoError);
             }

             function handleVideo(stream){   
             document.querySelector('#vidDisplay').src=window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
             }
             function videoError(e){
                 alert("some problem")
             }
         </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What you need is a live video streaming server; I suggest some more research to understand exactly what you're asking for. What are your constraints? You tagged this with PHP, but what kind of environment are you working with? An effective solution could be hundreds of lines of code or more.

Comment: thanks for reply.i am actually trying to build an android webview app for something in which user can stream a video to me via server or something.

Comment: I might reconsider your chosen technology and switch to a native Android app. Phones are slow to begin with, and streaming a video inside of a web-view would be a particularly resource intensive use case.

Comment: thanks, that is  a good idea. i am just doing different experiments. not for professional reason.

Answer (score 1):

For others to see a live stream from your webcam feed, you can use  Youtube Live or a paid site like tikilive, ustream, etc... (some even offer free accounts with ads).

You can use their in-browser software from the site, or 3rd party stream software to stream to the web.

All above mentioned options provide an embed-feature to embed the feed in your own php (or html) page.

Embed code can look like this for example in the Youtube Live case:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID-HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks for that too. I trying to build an android webview app for something in which user can stream a video to me via server or something